# performing infinite loop while awaiting input

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop, pwm

I have a little project I'm working on, it's fairly simple so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm using a raspberry pi to dim a single LED with some very crude PWM.

my PWM code looks like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
frequency = 0.005
dwell = 0.0001
while True:
    time.sleep(frequency)
    GPIO.output(7, 1)
    time.sleep(dwell)
    GPIO.output(7, 0)
```

Basically, in order for the LED to remain lit at the brightness determined by "dwell" I need that bit of code to continue looping forever.

What I would like to do is use something like

```
dwell=raw_input('brightness:')
```

so that while the PWM code is looping, I can drop in a new value for dwell to adjust the brightness of the LED.

all of my efforts so far result in one of the following:

a: the dimming loop executes once only and stops to await input
b: the dimming loop will execute infinitely but not allow further input

can one of you fine people provide me with a code example that explains how I can achieve this?

for those interested, ultimately what I would like to do is set the value of dwell via sockets and use a better form of PWM output to drive LED downlights. Baby steps :)

Comment: Do you want iterate until input has a certain value ?

Comment: i just want it to keep going forever using the dwell value.

the user needs to be able to adjust the value of dwell at all times

the loop should just keep going and just check the value of dwell each time it iterates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)!

```
# import the module
import threading

# define a function to be called in the other thread
def get_input():
    while True:
        dwell=raw_input()

# create a Thread object
input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input)

# start the thread
input_thread.start()

# now enter the infinite loop
while True:
    time.sleep(frequency)
    GPIO.output(7, 1)
    time.sleep(dwell)
    GPIO.output(7, 0)
```

There's probably something about [locks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) or [semaphores](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) or [mutex...es (mutices?)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html#module-mutex) missing here, but I don't know much about those. Simple things like this seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm afraid that your example did not work for me; it asked for input, set the brightness but did not allow further input

Comment: I'm sure this will post in a mess, I don't know how to format a reply - perhaps someone can help.....


import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
frequency = 0.005
dwell = 0.01

def get_input(dwell):
    dwell=raw_input("Brightness: ")

input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input(dwell))

input_thread.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(frequency)
    GPIO.output(7, 1)
    time.sleep(dwell)
    GPIO.output(7, 0)

Comment: @ByronHill You can easily change `get_input()` to keep asking for input. I'll edit my post. By the way, you can surround text with backquotes (`) to format it as code in comments (or in questions/answers).

Comment: this doesnt work either, it seems that the while loop in get_input() is preventing things from getting to the threading call.

If I remove the while, I can set the brightness (once) with the while in there it asks for input, and continues to ask for input however the LED doesn't light, suggesting to me that the thread is not starting. I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: @ByronHill It's working for me. Try adding a print statement just before the creation of the thread object to see if it gets to that point.

Comment: `import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
frequency = 0.05
dwell = 0.01

def get_input():
 while True:
  dwell=raw_input("Brightness: ")

input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input())

input_thread.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(frequency)
    GPIO.output(7, 1)
    time.sleep(dwell)
    GPIO.output(7, 0)`

I tried :(
`

Comment: done, not printing. we're getting stuck in the while in get_input

Comment: @ByronHill That doesn't make sense. `get_input()` isn't called until the second thread is started, and it's never called in the first thread. You probably made a mistake in something before my code. If you don't believe me, move the print statement to before `get_input()` is defined.

Comment: If i could figure out this damned formatting i could show you my code exactly :(

Comment: Move the print statement to before the definition of `get_input()`.

Comment: have done that, it prints. i've also stuck it in the while loop in the thread (presumably this would fill the buffer up with my print) it doesnt....

Comment: i can only post once every 90 minutes apparently. this is becoming extremely frustrating :(